# Real time detection of gaussian bell in signal in C#

Tags: c#, signal-processing

I have got a real time signal in c# which is stored in a List. I want to check if the signal pass from several points in order direction. In fact I want to detect real time if my signal performing a gaussian bell. What I have in my mind is to check if the signal pass from two thresholds in ascent order and in descent order. My signal takes values from 0-1 For example if the signal is passing from 0.25 with ascent order and from 0.75 again with ascent order and after that from 0.75 and 0.25 in descent order to detect my bell. How can I perform real time the above algorithm in c#. I store the signal value real time in a `List<double>`   called parts.

```
double currentValue = parts[parts.Count - 1];
double previousValue = parts[parts.Count - 2];
double diffValue = parts[parts.Count - 1] - parts[parts.Count - 2];

if (currentValue > 0.25 && (currentValue - previousValue) > 0)
{ 
// the first point is passed
}
if (currentValue  < 0.750 && (currentValue - previousValue) > 0)
{
 // the second point is passed
}
// the same for the descent order.  
}
```

What  I want is to count how many times my signal is performing the gaussian bell and to detect the time window returning the timestamps (from 0.25 point to 0.25).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your requirement. I know you described it like this, but can you take another stab? 
`What I have in my mind is to check if the signal pass from two 
 thresholds in ascent order and in descent order. For example if the
 signal is passing from 0.25 with ascent order and from 0.75 again with ascent order and after that from 0.75 and 0.25 in descent order to detect my bell`

Comment: What I am trying to do is to create a simple real time gaussian bell detector.  Thus i want to check if my signal is passing through 4 thresholds 0.25 and 0.75 when the signal is increasing the 0.75 and 0.25 when decreasing and those 4 condition to be met in order.

Comment: Do you have to check for specific thresholds (.25, .75, .75, 0.25)? Why not just calculate for the slope of the curve and count how many they have changed sign(+,-)?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I think he seeks for larger peaks. Small perturbations will also change in derivative sign. Windowed process may work, though.

Comment: You have a List of n decimals you call parts; in it are stored decimals between 0 and 1. What you wrote above says you want to grab the last value in your List and call it the current value, and the one before that and call it previous. But what I'm reading from your description and comments is that you want to detect if there are these values in this order, somewhere in your list: `[ .... 0.25 .....0.75 .... 0.75 .... 0.25 ...]` Is that correct?

Comment: If that's true, then you should try: var value = parts.First(item => item.value == 0.25).value; then find the next index ensuring it's greater...have to run but hope that gets you started. Good luck

Comment: Yes I want my signal to pass from those thresholds firstly in increasing mode and the in decreasing.

Comment: I am not sure that I am getting what you implied here with this var value = parts.First(item => item.value == 0.25).

Answer (score 1):

An improved answer, albeit in process. It should be refactored.

```
    void Main()
    {
        //Assuming a temporally ordered list
        List<double> ascOnly = new List<double> { 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8};
        List<double> gBell = new List<double> { 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.81, 0.6, 0.45, 0.32, 0.24, 0.1 };

        //make sure a first point below .25 exists. find it and its index in the List. (IndexOf also gets the first value so pv1 should always be the index of v1)
        var firstValue = gBell.FirstOrDefault(item => item < 0.25);
        var positionFirstValue = gBell.IndexOf(firstValue);
        Console.WriteLine("Starting below 0.25: " + firstValue + " , Position: " + positionFirstValue);

        //find the first point at or above .25 and its index in the List.
        var ascendingBottomThreshold = gBell.FirstOrDefault(item => item >= 0.25) ;
        var positionAscendingBottomThreshold = gBell.FindIndex(item => item == ascendingBottomThreshold);

        //make sure the first threshold is crossed after the initially small threshold (positive slope)
        if (positionAscendingBottomThreshold > positionFirstValue) //fyi FindIndex returns -1 if condition is not satisfied
            Console.WriteLine("First threshold at/above 0.25: " + ascendingBottomThreshold + " , Position: " + positionAscendingBottomThreshold);

        //find the first point at or above .75 and its index in the List
        var ascendingTopThreshold = gBell.FirstOrDefault(item => item >= 0.75) ;
        var positionAscendingTopThreshold = gBell.IndexOf(ascendingTopThreshold);

        //make sure the .75 threshold is crossed after the .25 threshold (positive slope)
        if (positionAscendingTopThreshold > positionAscendingBottomThreshold) //fyi FindIndex returns -1 if condition is not satisfied
            Console.WriteLine("Second threshold at/above 0.75: " + ascendingTopThreshold + " , Position: " + positionAscendingTopThreshold);


        //do i next have to cross .75 while maintaining a positive slope? or just never dip below .25? (assumed the latter)
        //make sure the signal that passed .25 never dips below .25 before it reaches .75.
        for (int p = positionAscendingBottomThreshold + 1 ; p < positionAscendingTopThreshold ; p++)
        {   
            if (gBell[p] < 0.25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fell below threshold ...does not qualify(?)");
            }
        }


        //assuming i need at least one more distinct point at or above .75; shows that signal did not just touch and go below, but actually crested.
        gBell.RemoveAt(positionAscendingTopThreshold);
        var descendingTopThreshold = gBell.FirstOrDefault(item => item >= 0.75) ;
        var positionDescendingTopThreshold = gBell.IndexOf(descendingTopThreshold);

        //make sure the .75 threshold is hit after the .75 threshold (positive slope)
        if (positionDescendingTopThreshold >= positionAscendingTopThreshold) //fyi FindIndex returns -1 if condition is not satisfied
            Console.WriteLine("Third threshold at/above 0.75: " + descendingTopThreshold + " , Position: " + positionDescendingTopThreshold);

        for (int p = positionAscendingTopThreshold ; p < positionDescendingTopThreshold ; p++) //just positionAscendingTopThreshold (not plus 1 because value removed)
        {   
            if (gBell[p] < 0.75)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fell below threshold ...does not qualify(?)");
            }
        }       

    //looking next for .25;
        //remove everything that got you 'up the hill'
        gBell.RemoveRange(0,positionDescendingTopThreshold);
        var descendingBottomThreshold = gBell.FirstOrDefault(item => item <= 0.25) ;
        var positionDescendingBottomThreshold = gBell.IndexOf(descendingBottomThreshold);

        //make sure the .25 threshold is hit after the second .75 threshold (downhill)
        //if (positionDescendingBottomThreshold >= positionDescendingTopThreshold) //fyi FindIndex returns -1 if condition is not satisfied
            Console.WriteLine("Fourth threshold at/below 0.25: " + descendingBottomThreshold + " , Position: " + positionDescendingBottomThreshold);

        for (int p = 1 ; p < positionDescendingBottomThreshold ; p++)
        {   
            if (gBell[p] > 0.75)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Rose above threshold ...does not qualify(?) " + gBell[p]);
            }
        }           

    }
```

Comment: The important thing here is that I want to detect the bell real time, not after the signal is complete to detect the bell.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. But your signal is in a List, right? So it's static. So you're checking values that are stale at the real time point you choose to check them. i.e., the example ascOnly would not check out, but if you ran again and it had become gBell then it should. Is that an accurate understanding?

Comment: I am just storing my signal to list(in fact my signal is fetched data real -time).  Yes, until now what I did was to use 4 if statements to check if my signal is passing through thresholds two in ascent order and two in descent order. I have got flags in order to check if those threshold are performed continuously.

Comment: I am guess that FirstOrDefault finds the first occurence of the statement, How can I return the second time that this condition is met?

Comment: Right - first occurrence. If you pursue this line of thinking, it seems there are two ways: one, remove the first instance from the list (example in edited answer); or two, start looking after the current index. If the edited answer isn't more helpful we can try again. GL.